# Does Xcode 4.5.2 automatically prefix synthesized BOOL getters with is

Tags: objective-c, xcode, boolean

I just noticed that I had a BOOL declared as `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL    userAuthorized;` and I was about to write my own getter for it and automatically Xcode autocompleted with `- (BOOL)isUserAuthorized`

So I suspect it's not necessary anymore to write `@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isUserAuthorized) BOOL userAuthorized;` ?

Comment: Huh, good question. And finally a question tagged `xcode` that **is actually** about Xcode. +1.

Comment: I think it's more related to the llvm compiler, even though clearly it comes with XCode

Comment: I think it's probably a good guess by Xcode. See Gabriele's answer.

Comment: It's more than a good guess. There's some work needed to translate `self.active` to `[self isActive]` and such work is made by the compiler. The cool finding here is that is done without us telling him the name explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently if you provide your own implementation of the `BOOL` getter, the compiler is smart enough to figure out that `isActive` is the getter for the `active` property.

Nonetheless if you synthesize the getter you still have to provide `getter=isActive` in order to use that signature for the getter instead of `active`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you don't need to write  `getter = isUserAuthorized` in property when you explicitly mention the getter of `BOOL` property and you also don't need to synthesize properties as xcode automatically do it for you.

Comment: why is this incorrect? LLVM 4.0 automatically synthesize properties

Comment: The first half. LLVM does not give special treatment to synthesis of `BOOL` properties like that.